# Uncaught TypeError: X is not a function. While using javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout, infinite-loop

I'm playing with JavaScript and see following error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: div is not a function.

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function createDiv(interval) {
    let radius = 300;
    let int = interval;
    var f = 0;
    var s = 2 * Math.PI / 180;
    let timerId = window.setTimeout(function tick()
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'circle';
        div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        div.style.left = (radius + radius * Math.cos(f)) + 'px';
        div.style.top = (radius + radius * Math.sin(f)) + 'px';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        f += s;
        setTimeout(tick, int);
    }, int)

}

let div = createDiv(10);
div();
```

I left the following for simplicity:

```
function createDiv(interval) {
    let timerId = window.setTimeout(function tick()
    {
        setTimeout(tick, 10);
    }, 10)
}

let div = createDiv(10);
div();
```

This is essentially an infinite loop. And error occurs when calling `div()` but loop is working.

What is wrong? And how it fix?

Comment: `createDiv(10)` invokes the function, and it will return `void` as your have no return statement in the function. Therefore `div` is not a function but `undefined`. Did you try console logging `div?` after it was set?

Comment: Thanks. Yes in console div is `undefined`. How it fix?

Comment: What do you think its supposed to be? As soon as you use `createDiv` it will run the `setTimeout`. Look at answer response.

Comment: What is `div()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no closure here: you're calling a function that returns `undefined` and attempting to call `undefined()` as if it were a function. Simply call your function like `createDiv(10);`. Note that I've added a height and width to your div so the result is visible.

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function createDiv(interval) {
  let radius = 300;
  let int = interval;
  var f = 0;
  var s = 2 * Math.PI / 180;
  let timerId = window.setTimeout(function tick() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'circle';
    div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    div.style.height = div.style.width = "50px";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    f += s;
    setTimeout(tick, int);
  }, int)
}

createDiv(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function createDiv(interval) {
    let radius = 300;
    let int = interval;
    var f = 0;
    var s = 2 * Math.PI / 180;
    window.setTimeout(function tick()
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'circle';
        div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        div.style.left = (radius + radius * Math.cos(f)) + 'px';
        div.style.top = (radius + radius * Math.sin(f)) + 'px';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        f += s;
        setTimeout(tick, int);
    }, int)

}

let div = createDiv(10);
console.log(div);
try {
  div();
} catch (err) {
  console.log('error')
}


function createDivSmall(interval) {
   window.setTimeout(function tick()
    {
        setTimeout(tick, interval);
    }, 10)
}

let divSmall = createDivSmall(10);
console.log(divSmall);
try {
  divSmall();
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Small error')
}
```

In your `createDiv` function you are not returning anything, so the default behavior is to return `undefined`. This sets `div = undefined`. At this point `div` is not a function so trying to invoke it will throw an error. `createDiv` is starting the loop for you and running it, there is not need to set a variable to the return value.